# Wordpress post page content width too wide in mobile devices

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

im currently working on a blogproject. Everything works fine except on mobile screens. I've made a custom theme using the bootstrap framework and when i put the_content(); inside bootstraps div class="container"> it looks wierd and gets too large for the screen. If i remove the .container div it works but then i don't get the text centered and the prefered width, it just covers the whole screen.

I've tried everything i can come up with without success.

Here's the blog: http://www.hannaoeberg.com

Comment: [Here](http://i.imgur.com/GbNUhxR.png) is an image of your site on iPhone 5 screen settings. I don't see any issues with the content width. Could you explain further?

Comment: I don't see any issues with the content on mobile devices either.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem with overflow:hidden , that's why :) big thanks anyway!